# How to solve: Conversion operators cannot convert from an interface type

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, interface, com

I've wrapped the **[INetFwRule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365344%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** members, I've put the properties in a custom type named `FirewallRule`, and for elegancy to save time in other parts of the code when performing conversions from `INetFwRule` to `FirewallRule` I tried to write this implicit converter:

C#:

```
public static explicit operator FirewallRule(INetFwRule rule) {
    return new FirewallRule {
        Action = (FirewallRuleAction)rule.Action,
        ApplicationName = rule.ApplicationName,
        Description = rule.Description,
        // etc...
    };
}
```

Vb.Net (original):

```
Public Shared Narrowing Operator CType(ByVal rule As INetFwRule) As FirewallRule

    Return New FirewallRule With {
        .Action = DirectCast(rule.Action, FirewallRuleAction),
        .ApplicationName = rule.ApplicationName,
        .Description = rule.Description,
        ' etc ...
    }

End Operator
```

However, I get this error in the `rule` parameter:

> Conversion operators cannot convert from an interface type

There is an approach to solve this to be able write the `CType`?.

Comment: @Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå That is easy to say, but... hehe. thanks for comment!

Comment: Your question seems to suggest that this is possible in VB, but not C# - however it's invalid in either language.

Comment: @Dave Doknjas No, I only put code in C# because much people downvotes questions if they don't see a code in the tagged language... much people doesn't understand that the OP could look for a C# answer too, that is the only reason, sorry for the confusion that has caused. Thanks for comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compiler prohibits you from defining conversion operators that take interfaces as parameters, because it considers such conversion already defined (i.e. the built-in ability to cast).

You would need to use some other syntax to initiate conversions of `INetFwRule` to `FirewallRule` - for example, an extension to `INetFwRule`:

```
public static class NetFwRuleExt {
    public static FirewallRule ToFirewallRule(this INetFwRule rule) {
        return new FirewallRule {
            Action = (FirewallRuleAction)rule.Action,
            ApplicationName = rule.ApplicationName,
            Description = rule.Description,
            // etc...
        };
    }
}
```

Instead of writing

```
FirewallRule newRule = (FirewallRule)someRule;
```

clients of your API would write

```
FirewallRule newRule = someRule.ToFirewallRule();
```

Comment: Well this limitation is unfortunate because in my case that assumption by the compiler is just wrong.  My class does not implement that interface, and the interface var could be null (Nothing in VB).  I suppose I can accomplish it by going the other direction and creating a static (Shared) method on the destination class that does the narrowing conversion.